# How can I change the value of a variable of an object that is in a vector of objects that is whithin a class?

Tags: c++

I'm getting way out of my regular field to do this and I've been running into some stupidly complex situations.
I've declared a class which has a variable "int activacion" and then I've made another class which has a vector of objects of this previous type.
Then I've done another class which has a vector of the lattest.
I'd find it completely normal if I just couldn't go on but the thing is I'm not having trouble READING the values using getValue(), and I just can't seem to be able to change it using the same line of code with setValue();

```
getElementoVectorCapas(i).getElementoVectorNeuronas(j).getActivacion()<<endl;
```

This works.

```
getElementoVectorCapas(1).getElementoVectorNeuronas(0).setActivacion(1);
```

This doesn't.
It's like the value is fixed. It compiles allright, it just does not change the value.
Thanks in advance.
I've cut&pasted just the bits that seemed relevant. Adding a & sign just on the signature won't let me compile.

```
class CNeurona{
  private:      
      int activacion;
  public:
     void setActivacion(int x){
            activacion = x;
            }
       int getActivacion(){
           return activacion;
 }
 };  
 class CCapa{
  private:          
      std::vector<CNeurona> vectorNeuronas;
  public:
         CCapa(int i_numNeuronas, int i_numeroInputsPorNeurona){
             setNumNeuronas(i_numNeuronas);
             for(c=0;c<i_numNeuronas;c++){                        
                    vectorNeuronas.push_back(CNeurona(i_numeroInputsPorNeurona));                   
                   }             
             }                 
         CNeurona getElementoVectorNeuronas(int x){
                return vectorNeuronas[x];
                }
};
   class CRed{
  private:              
          std::vector<CCapa> vectorCapas;
 public:
 void setVectorEntrada(){                 

              for(j=0;j<numNeuronasEntrada;j++){
                   cout<<"Introduce activaciones de capa de entrada, N"<<j<<": "<<endl;
                   cin >> i;       
getElementoVectorCapas(0).getElementoVectorNeuronas(j).setActivacion(i);                                          
                   }
```

Comment: Please show some **small**, self-contained code sample that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Show signatures of `getElementoVectorCapas`, `getElementoVectorNeuronas`. I think they returns value, not reference.

Comment: @ForEveR: +1 highly likely the the first vector, second vector, or both, are returned by value rather than reference. Would know more if we ever saw the code requested.

Comment: Please reduce the example as much as you can, you don't need the CRed class to illustrate your problem, you can leave out a lot of the constructor code and you don't need the CNeurona class, you could have used a simple int instead. By reducing your problem like this by yourself you have a better understanding of *what* is going wrong *where* and may also be able to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 2):

```
CNeurona getElementoVectorNeuronas(int x)
```

returns a **copy** of the `CNeurona` object in the vector. When you call

```
getElementoVectorNeuronas(j).setActivacion(i);
```

You call the `setActivation` method on a **copy** of the `CNeurona` object, returned by `getElementoVectorNeuronas`, this **copy** is subsequently discarded.

You need to use a reference instead; your function should be

```
CNeurona& getElementoVectorNeuronas(int x)
```

And if `getElementoVectorCapas` returns a copy too - it is an error in your case, it should return a reference.

Comment: It works. Can't believe it. Thank you so much. Really, thankyou.

Comment: On the other hand, it is considered bad design to return a handle to one's intrisics (it lowers encapsulation).